# Windows Forms Surface Pen Eraser Detection

Tags: c#, .net, surface, pen, eraser

I'm trying to detect whether the current mouse (pen) press on a surface pro pen was from the nib or the eraser. I realise this can be done relatively easy in WPF/ink, is there any way to detect this using standard win forms?

Comment: Interestingly there's an article on .NET 4.7 release that says there's now support for WM_POINTER stylus detection. Anyone know anything about this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/